# How to get ftp files in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp

I have a ftp server. I can get csv files using `nlist` method. Ftp file name is a timestamp as like as `20220331235501.csv`.

I fetch data using this code:

```
require 'net/ftp'

ftps = Net::FTP.new(ENV['FTP_HOST'], username: ENV['FTP_USERNAME'], password: ENV['FTP_PASSWORD'], ssl: true, debug_mode: true, passive: true)

end_time = DateTime.now
end_time = end_time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M').to_i
start_time = get_start_time(item, end_time)

while current_time <= end_time do
  day_str = current_time
  files = ftps.nlst("#{day_str}*.csv")
          
  files.each do |f|
    puts f
  end

  current_time = current_time + 1
end

def get_start_time(item, end_time)   
  # returns last sync file name as like as 20220331235508.csv

  last_file_name = FtpFileSync.find_by(folder_name: item)&.file_name
  return nil if last_file_name.blank?

  last_file_time = last_file_name.split('.')[0]
  return nil if last_file_time.blank?

  # returns 202203312355 
  last_file_time_minute = last_file_time[0, last_file_time.length - 2].to_i        
  last_file_time_minute.blank? ? (end_time - 5) : last_file_time_minute
end
```

**Problem**

When last file is `20220331235508.csv`, I increment the day like as `20220331 + 1 = 20220332` but it raise error since there is no day 32 in calendar.

For resolving this issue, I want that I will get last file after `20220331235508.csv` file and sync will start from that file.

Example: I get the last file sync is 20220331235509.csv from DB query and in ftp folder,

2022004010001.csv file exists after the 20220331235509.csv.

How can I get all files after the 20220331235509.csv from the ftp not increment current time?

Comment: Sorry, for me it's not clear how do you increment a timestapm. Could you provide more examples what `get_start_time` takes and what it should return?

Answer (score -1):

Use `Time` class to operate with the dates and print it with [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) in the format you need.

```rb
irb(main):021:0> t = Time.utc(2022,3,31)
=> 2022-03-31 00:00:00 UTC
irb(main):022:0> t.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
=> "20220331000000"
irb(main):023:0> t = t + 86400 # seconds
=> 2022-04-01 00:00:00 UTC
irb(main):024:0> t.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
=> "20220401000000"
```